# Capistrano v2 to v3 upgrade confusing

Tags: rubygems, capistrano, capistrano3

Can any body kindly help me to upgrade capistrano from version2 to version.3. I am confused of referring different links. As more changes are in version 3 compared to version 2, I am getting error continuously while upgrading. Still I couldn't find no link which explains clearly all the steps. Can anybody help me on right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade documentation is here:
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/

Also, the release announcement contains a lot of information on the changes:
http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html

Without more details it's impossible to help you more than that.